# Dependencies fail to install, cannot install picamera on pi3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspicam, dpkg, python-3

When I run `apt-get install python3-picamera` it fails with different dependency issues like:
`files list file for package 'libparams-util-perl' is missing final newline`

or

`files list file for package ''libpam0g-dev.' is missing final newline`

I've run `sudo apt update;` and `sudo apt upgrade` but neither seem to help.

I also read to delete the entries for the corresponding packages, and reinstall them in `/var/lib/dpkg/<package>` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Can someone please help?

Comment: picamera's installed by default on Raspbian (has been for quite a while now); are you using Raspbian, or some other distro on your Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, have you tried installing it as superuser?

```
sudo apt-get install python3-picamera
```

Alternatively, are you sure you need this library? I've been programming my PiCamera on a RPi3 and didn't need to install any additional libraries. Have you tried just enabling the camera on Interfacing Options at:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and running a simple example to see if it works?

Comment: `apt` does work here instead of `apt-get` — see [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks for the info! I'll edit the answer.